# How to use private struct inside of friend function?

Tags: c++

I have a function which prints entries of a "Polynomial" class:

```
void Polynomial::print()
{
    Term* pos = first;

    while(pos != NULL){
        std::cout << "y=" << pos->coeff << "x^" << pos->power;

        if(pos->next != NULL){
            std::cout << "+";
        }
            pos = pos->next;
        }
    std::cout<<endl;
}
```

and I would like to translate it so that I can use it with *cout* instead. I 
made the following friend function:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, const Polynomial &Poly)
{
   Term* pos = Poly.first;

   while(pos != NULL){
       out << "y=" << pos->coeff << "x^" << pos->power;

      if(pos->next != NULL){
         out << "+";
      }
      pos = pos->next;
   }
   out<<endl;
}
```

Which told me `‘Term’ was not declared in this scope`. *Term* is a private struct defined inside the class *Polynomial*, how do can I use it as a type inside the friend function?

Comment: You probably need `Polynomial::Term`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Term` is defined inside `Polynomial`, so you need to refer to it by its full name `Polynomial::Term` when using it outside of the scope of the `Polinomial` class.

```
Polynomial::Term* pos = Poly.first;
```